# Augmented Reality with Locations Library (iOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

I'm in need of a recommendation of a **free** AR library that will allow me to display location indicators (2D views) on top of a camera overlay (you probably know what I mean). 
So far I've tried using [this iOS library](https://github.com/promet/PRAugmentedReality), but it seems to be out of shape since I did not get good results -> somehow the views got displaced and I did not grasp the math behind it.
I'm also in need of an Android version, but that can wait, so I'd like an iOS recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I've used BeyondAR on Android a couple of times and It works:

https://github.com/BeyondAR/beyondar

You just need to have the coordinates of the object to show and the image.